# Does fetch always sends UTC timestamps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, timezone, timezone-offset

I am developing an application when I am saving some reminders in a database. Below is the code snippet of this function:

```
const createNewSmsReminder = (textBody, dateTime) => {
        console.log(dateTime)
        let body = {
                    'content' : "This is a test",
                    'when' : dateTime
                    }
        saveNewReminderAction(urlParams.uuid, body)
    }
```

which calls the saveNewReminderAction:

```
export const createNewSmsReminderAction = (uuid, body) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: CREATE_NEW_SMS_REMINDER_PENDING})
    fetch(config.url.API_URL+'/api/subscription/'+uuid+'/reminder', p_authorisation('POST', body))
        .then(response=> response.json())
        .then(data => dispatch({type: CREATE_NEW_SMS_REMINDER_SUCCESS, payload: data}))
        .catch(error => dispatch({type: CREATE_NEW_SMS_REMINDER_ERROR, payload: error}))
}
```

On the createNewSms `console.log(dateTime)` returns:
`Mon Sep 28 2020 13:04:42 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

but when I observe the payload of the request I notice that the timestamp has been converted to UTC format:

```
{
   content: "This is a test", 
   when: "2020-09-28T17:04:42.158Z"
}
```

Is this normal behaviour enforced by fetch/chrome/something else I cannot even think of, or am I doing something wrong? Also if this is normal, is it consistent across different browsers, or I am looking to nasty surprises in the future? Is there any way to enforce it? (It is worth mentioning that this is the exact behaviour I am after)

**EDIT**: Answering to questions below here is my p_authorisation method:

```
const p_authorisation = (method, body) => {
    let auth = {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Origin': '',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
            // 'skip_before_action' : 'verify_authenticity_token'
        },
        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : ''
    }
    return auth
}
```

Comment: What is `p_authorisation`?

Comment: I have added the method on my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though left out of your question, I'll assume the following:

- The `dateTime` parameter passed to `createNewSmsReminder` is indeed a `Date` object
- The `p_authorisation` function calls `JSON.stringify` over the `body` object passed in and assigns it to the `body` property of the object it returns.

When you stringify a `Date` object, or an object containing a `Date` object, the [`Date.toJson`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) function is invoked, which in turn calls [`Date.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to create the ISO 8601 string representation that's used in the JSON.

The `toISOString` function *always* returns a UTC representation of the `Date` object.  This doesn't have anything to do with `fetch` - it's just how the `Date` object works.

The `Date` object internally only stores one thing - a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with millisecond precision.  Thus, despite its name, it is not a *date*, but rather it's a UTC based *timestamp*.

Additionally, when you call `console.log` on a `Date` object - the behavior is implementation-specific.  There is no specification that defines what the output should be.  (ECMAScript defines `Date` but not `Console`, and the the [WHATWG Console standard](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/) declined my request to formalize the output of logging `Date` objects [in issue #132](https://github.com/whatwg/console/issues/132).)

The current situation is that *some* implementations will log the output of `toString` - which is in terms of local time in a human-readable format, and other implementations will log the output of `toISOString`, which is in terms of UTC and in the ISO 8601 extended format.

Since the implementation can vary - you should not log a `Date` object directly.  Instead, log the string output of one of those two functions.  In other words if you do `console.log(dateTime.toISOString())` you will get the same results shown in your JSON.

In short - this is normal behavior.  Your program is working correctly.

Comment: Totally correct, but too many assumptions imo. Better leave a comment first asking for details.

Comment: Hi @Matt Johnson-Pint, thanks for you response. Your assumptions are in fact correct, I am indeed using the JSON.stringify over the request body within p_authorisation method. In fact I have edited my initial question to add the method. Thank you for taking the time to get into the depths of this issue, your response has helped me to get a good understanding on the behaviour of my method.